# How to conditional delete regex

Tags: python, regex, string, nlp

I am trying to process word files where I have to summarize this:

```
str = '''red (5), blue (3 left, right, up), green(2 one, two, three), yellow(7)'''
```

to this:

```
{red:5, blue:3, green:2, yellow:7}
```

Only the numeric value is important to me in the brackets.

I have tried working around with some long code but it doesn't work very well so basically, I want a simple solution something like:

```
# discard everything else in bracket except for the numeric value
re.replace(r'(.)', '**NUMERIC VALUE**', str)
# also split based on a ',' that is outside the bracket
re.compile('\),').split('str')
```

I couldn't figure out the *NUMERIC VALUE** part and how to conditional split based on regex
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Details missing. Are the numbers guaranteed to always be the first and only first element inside the parenthesis?

Comment: numbers are always first and I always want the first number because in some cases there are dates inside the bracket too after the number,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script produces desired result for the string in your question, but more testing on real data is necessary:

```
import re

s = '''red (5), blue (3 left, right, up), green(2 one, two, three), yellow(7)'''

d = dict(re.findall(r'([a-z]+)\s*\(.*?(\d+)', s))

print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'red': '5', 'blue': '3', 'green': '2', 'yellow': '7'}
```

Comment: With few edits, it works perfectly. Thank you so much. One thing though - how did you replace the regex with numeric value here in last part     '\(.*?(\d+)'

Comment: @JaySabir Maybe I don't understand - I create 2-element tuples with regex groups, first group is color name and second is number (hence `\d+`). Then I feed those tuples do `dict()` constructor to obtain the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your issue: https://regex101.com/r/QQ19Qi/1

```
import re

regex = r"(.*)\ ?\((\d+).*\).*"

test_str = "red (5), blue (3 left, right, up), green(2 one, two, three), yellow(7)"

subst = "\\1:\\2"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```